# Remove non-dichotomous columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having the hardest time using a function to conditionally removing a column in R if the values are not binary (e.g., 0 or 1). In order for me to run a statistical analysis, I need all columns to be dichotomous, and I need a function that can be applied to multiple dfs. So far, I seem to only be able to find results that remove rows...

For example, if one df1 has 3 columns (col1, col2, and col3) but col3 had more than 2 distinct values, I'd like to remove that. Similarly, if df2 had 5 columns and only 1 of those columns was dichotomous, I'd like to remove all four, and so on and so forth.

Some posts suggested removing them by name but the problem is that I need to run this on 100s of dataframes, so identifying every column and manually removing them would not be optimal.

Currently, I've tried:

```
data %>% select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between (., 0, 1)))
```

This is unfortunately not working and I am getting multiple errors. Also, I'm not sure if this keeps columns that have NAs (but I'd like to keep those columns as well!)

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion 1: replace `&&` by `&`. `&&` works only for vectors of length `1` and therefore removes the rest.

Comment: Suggestion 2: you don't want the variable to be between 0 and 1 - you want it to be **either `0` or `1`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout this one:

```
dichotomous <- function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% c(0,1))
dichotomous2 <- function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) %in% c(2,1)

df %>%
    select_if(dichotomous)

df %>%
    select_if(dichotomous2)
```

The `dichotomous()` is for one-hot coded (or dummy) variables - i.e. `1`-`0`. `dichotomous2()` is for truly dichotomous, i.e. there are two distinct values.